# Scrape values from HTML select/option tags in R

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying (fairly unsuccessfully) to scrape some data from a website (www.majidata.co.ke) using R. I've managed to scrape the HTML and parse it but now a little unsure how to extract the bits I actually need!

Using the `XML` library I scrape my data using this code:

```
majidata_get <- GET("http://www.majidata.go.ke/town.php?MID=MTE=&SMID=MTM=")
majidata_html <- htmlTreeParse(content(majidata_get, as="text"))
```

This leaves me with (Large) XMLDocumentContent. There is a drop-down list on the webpage and I want to scrape the values from it (which relate to the names and ID no. of different towns). The bits I want to extract are the numbers between `<option value ="XXX">` and the name following it in capital letters.

```
<div class="regiondata">
       <div id="town_data">
        <select id="town" name="town" onchange="town_data(this.value);">
         <option value="0" selected="selected">[SELECT TOWN]</option>
         <option value="611">AHERO</option>
         <option value="635">AKALA</option>
         <option value="625">AWASI</option>
         <option value="628">AWENDO</option>
         <option value="749">BAHATI</option>
         <option value="327">BANGALE</option>
```

Ideally, I'd like to have these in a data.frame where the first column is the number and second column is the name e.g.

```
ID       Name
611      AHERO
635      AKALA
625      AWASI
```

etc.

I'm not really sure where to go from here. I had thought to use regex and match the pattern within the text, though I've read from a number of forums that this is a bad idea an that its better/more efficient to use the xpath. Not really sure where to start with this though other than thinking I need to use `xpathApply`somehow.

Comment: Here's a simple example of some `XML` extraction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21844528/r-parsing-xml-to-a-desired-mapping-table/21845936#21845936

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The very new [rvest](http://github.com/hadley/rvest) package makes quick work of this and lets you use sane CSS selectors, too.

**UPDATED** Incorporates the second request (see comments below)

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

# gets data from the second popup
# returns a data frame of town_id, town_name, area_id, area_name
addArea <- function(town_id, town_name) {

  # make the AJAX URL and grab the data
  url <- sprintf("http://www.majidata.go.ke/ajax-list-area.php?reg=towns&type=projects&id=%s",
                 town_id)
  subunits <- html(url)

  # reformat into a data frame with the town data
  data.frame(town_id=town_id,
             town_name=town_name,
             area_id=subunits %>% html_nodes("option") %>% html_attr("value"),
             area_name=subunits %>% html_nodes("option") %>% html_text(),
             stringsAsFactors=FALSE)[-1,]

}

# get data from the first popup and put it into a dat a frame
majidata <- html("http://www.majidata.go.ke/town.php?MID=MTE=&SMID=MTM=")
maji <- data.frame(town_id=majidata %>% html_nodes("#town option") %>% html_attr("value"),
                   town_name=majidata %>% html_nodes("#town option") %>% html_text(),
                   stringsAsFactors=FALSE)[-1,]

# pass in the name and id to our addArea function and make the result into
# a data frame with all the data (town and area)
combined <- do.call("rbind.data.frame",
                    mapply(addArea, maji$town_id,  maji$town_name,
                           SIMPLIFY=FALSE, USE.NAMES=FALSE))

# row names aren't super-important, but let's keep them tidy
rownames(combined) <- NULL

str(combined)

## 'data.frame':    1964 obs. of  4 variables:
##  $ town_id  : chr  "611" "635" "625" "628" ...
##  $ town_name: chr  "AHERO" "AKALA" "AWASI" "AWENDO" ...
##  $ area_id  : chr  "60603030101" "60107050201" "60603020101" "61103040101" ...
##  $ area_name: chr  "AHERO" "AKALA" "AWASI" "ANINDO" ...


head(combined)

##   town_id town_name     area_id area_name
## 1     611     AHERO 60603030101     AHERO
## 2     635     AKALA 60107050201     AKALA
## 3     625     AWASI 60603020101     AWASI
## 4     628    AWENDO 61103040101    ANINDO
## 5     628    AWENDO 61103050401      SARE
## 6     749    BAHATI 73101010101    BAHATI
```

Comment: thanks to both, both ways work perfectly. I've a second question though. There is another drop down list that appears next to the first, once you've selected 'town' offering you a list of sub-units within each town. Is it possible to use the same approach to scrape data from the second list? e.g. if I was interested in 'Nairobi' can I use either of the above approaches to scrape all of the sub-units within 'Nairobi' a reflected in the second drop down box: 'SELECT AREA'?

Comment: I am learning the tools of SO but marty_c you may need to start your comment with the @tag of the two answerers for them to see your comment.  Second, the approaches they offer will work but the URL(s) will change for the second drop down.

Comment: As @lawyeR adeptly pointed out, it's just grabbing another URL. Technically, you should have opened up a new question :-) You need to get comfortable with browser "Developer" menu/tools since finding this one was just a matter of seeing what got called to make that popup. NOTE: this takes a few seconds to run since it's making many AJAX calls. Adding a progress bar (recommended) is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Also, I'd highly suggest saving out the resultant data frame to an `rda` file (or CSV, or something). Running this scraping code repeatedly is a great way to get your IP address banned from sites. It's unlikely "town" & "area" are going to change that frequently (if at all).

Comment: @hrbmstr: I am pleased to have 10+ rep points but I have no idea why they were bestowed on me.  I gave no answer, just a modest comment.  If someone upvotes my comment, wouldn't I see that from the little flag?

Comment: Looks like you got it for your answer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25968137/r-data-subset-restructuring/25970603#25970603

Comment: @hrbmstr thanks for all your help. I've made a lot of progress now. I'm basically trying to scrape the mapped 'polygon' data that relates to all of these areas within certain towns see (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/114425/parse-php-html-to-shapefile-or-similar). I've managed to get all of the polygons or outlines of each area within the towns. Next step is to get some of the attribute data that is displayed in the table on the right-hand side of the webpage. Will have a play around though and see what I come up with. thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Using xpath expressions with HTML is almost always a better choice than regex. Given this data you can extract what you're after with

```
options<-getNodeSet(xmlRoot(majidata_html), "//select[@id='town']/option")

ids <- sapply(options, xmlGetAttr, "value")
names <- sapply(options, xmlValue)

data.frame(ID=ids, Name=names)
```

which returns

```
   ID          Name
1   0 [SELECT TOWN]
2 611         AHERO
3 635         AKALA
4 625         AWASI
5 628        AWENDO
6 749        BAHATI
...
```