# R data subset restructuring

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, plyr, apply

I am fairly new to R/Rstudio and I am still learning how to do certain operations.
I have the following data set. For columns I have Operating Region, type of element(CA,OBU), sub-element and Net Revenue. 
Currently the data is quite big(50 000 rows) and I want to get a summary of Operating region by element,sub-element and NR.
Example

```
 Operating Region   Element Sub-Element NR
 Asia        CA     CA123   50 000
 America    OBU     EFK456  35 000
```

Could someone please guide me on how to accomplish this? 
Any relevant readings/examples would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you want the summary statistics of `NR` by `Operating, Region, Element, Sub-Element`?

Comment: Or use `library(doBy); summaryBy`

Answer (score 1):

Using the data below to return the data frame object "data," you can use the `dplyr` package to organize results in many different ways.  Here is one example:

```
data <- data.frame("OperatingRegion" = c("Asia", "America"), "Region" = c("CA", "OBU"), "Element" = c("CA123", "EFK456"), "SubElement" = c(50000, 35000))

require(dplyr)
results <- data %.%
  group_by(OperatingRegion) %.%
  summarise(SubE = sum(SubElement, na.rm = TRUE))

Source: local data frame [2 x 2]

  OperatingRegion  SubE
1         America 35000
2            Asia 50000
```

After loading the package, you provide dplyr the data frame and then, using the special operators %.% or %>%, group_by whatever single or multiple variables you want.  Then, call `summarise` to create sums, medians, averages or whatever computation you want.