# How scrape values from HTML select/option tags in R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I have a similar problem as is shown in the this question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25965785/scrape-values-from-html-select-option-tags-in-r).

I am scraping this [web page](https://catastroalava.tracasa.es/descargas/?lang=es) and I would like to download the text in the option value, I mean, where you can read "Seleccionar municipio", that is, the next node in the html code:

```
<select name="txtMunicipio" id="txtMunicipio" class="inputText"><option value="">-------------------------------------</option>
  <option value="001">ALEGRIA-DULANTZI</option>
  <option value="002">AMURRIO</option>
  <option value="049">AÑANA</option>
  <option value="003">ARAMAIO</option>
  <option value="006">ARMIÑON</option>
  <option value="037">ARRAIA-MAEZTU</option>
  ...
  </select>
```

And I would like to obtain something like follows

```
ID   Name
001  ALEGRIA-DULANTZI
002  AMURRIO
049  AÑANA
...
```

So what I have tried is something similar as the question I made reference before, using the next lines in R:

```
web_page<-read_html("https://catastroalava.tracasa.es/descargas/?lang=es")

web_page %>% html_nodes("select#txtMunicipio.inputText option") %>% html_attr("value")
web_page %>% html_nodes(".inputText option") %>% html_attr("value")
web_page %>% html_nodes("#txtMunicipio option") %>% html_attr("value")

web_page %>% html_nodes("select#txtMunicipio.inputText option") %>% html_text()
web_page %>% html_nodes(".inputText option") %>% html_text()
web_page %>% html_nodes("#txtMunicipio option") %>% html_text()
```

But what I ever obtain is:

```
character(0)
```

Please, could you help me what are the parameters that I have to put in `html_nodes` function to download the information?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's a bit presumptuous to self-identify this as a "not duplicated" question. The data is there, but the page is dynamically built and the data is in a script tag and there *are many, many, many* SO web scraping + R questions that deal with that scenario.

Comment: Sorry @hrbrmstr, but I have tried almost everything, thanks for your changes.

Comment: Given https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1457051+%5Br%5D+%5Bweb-scraping%5D+v8 I'm not sure "everything" is accurate. I'm rly not trying to be snarky or mean, too. Web scraping is a domain all it's own and its as important to become familiar with it (if you are going to work with web content) and all the "gotchas" as it is any primary domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your incorrect assertion regarding question duplication notwithstanding, the data is on the page. I suspect you used Selector Gadget or some such tool to identify the rendered page nodes and never viewed the original source of the web site (this is a super common issue and one reason I have much disdain for Selector Gadget and the prevalence of advice that says to use it first before any other investigation).

The popup is built dynamically after page load and here's the source:

[image]

I've personally authored [more than a few SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1457051+%5Br%5D+%5Bweb-scraping%5D+v8) that show how to get such data, but we'll ignore the existence of those for this.

The general idea is to get just enough javascript (that will work with the V8 package since it's based on a rly rly old V8 engine version) to be let it parse the data and then marshal the values back to R.

```
library(rvest)
library(V8)
library(purrr)

ctx <-v8() # we need to convert javascript to R

pg <- read_html("https://catastroalava.tracasa.es/descargas/?lang=es")

html_nodes(pg, xpath=".//script[contains(., 'ALEGRIA-DULANTZI')]") %>% 
  html_text() %>% 
  gsub("function escribeMunicipios.*$", "", .) %>%  # get rid of everything but the data
  ctx$eval(.)

ctx$get("municipios") %>% 
  setNames(c("ID", "Name"))
##     ID                 Name
## 1  001     ALEGRIA-DULANTZI
## 2  002              AMURRIO
## 3  049                AÑANA
## 4  003              ARAMAIO
## 5  006              ARMIÑON
## 6  037        ARRAIA-MAEZTU
## 7  008   ARRAZUA-UBARRUNDIA
## 8  004           ARTZINIEGA
## 9  009            ASPARRENA
## 10 010                AYALA
## ... goes on ...
```

Comment: Wow man! you're the master scraper, thank you. You're right, I used selector gadget, thanks for your help.

Comment: Definitely take a look at [Developer Tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) (all modern browsers have them) and also try to keep the kbd shortcut for "view original source" (it's crazy but all browsers seem to have different shortcuts for that) in active memory as they will both be valuable aids.

Comment: Maybe what I need is a web scraping course from you, haha, thank you man...